# Lifetime mismatch in a double mutable borrow

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm trying to modify the borrow of a mutable value, here is a minimal example:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut w: [char; 5] = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'];
    let mut wslice: &mut [char] = &mut w;
    advance_slice(&mut wslice);
    advance_slice(&mut wslice);
}

fn advance_slice(s: &mut &mut [char]) {
    let new: &mut [char] = &mut s[1..];
    *s = new;
}
```

the compiler gives me this error:

```
error[E0623]: lifetime mismatch
  --> src/main.rs:10:10
   |
8  | fn advance_slice(s: &mut &mut [char]) {
   |                     ----------------
   |                     |
   |                     these two types are declared with different lifetimes...
9  |     let new: &mut [char] = &mut s[1..];
10 |     *s = new;
   |          ^^^ ...but data from `s` flows into `s` here
```

I've tried to give the same lifetime to both borrow, without success.
Also this works if I remove the mutability of `w`.

Comment: What what what? Please explain why you have/need a `&mut &mut` variable? This is absolutly uncessary. This isn't C, please return an array instead, or modify the passed, but don't mess with "pointer pointer".

Comment: Btw: Rust has a `String` type, we don't use char arrays ;) Looks like you have a C background.

Comment: I don't really **need** this, I was just wondering if this is possible :)

Comment: @hellow Passing a mutable pointer to a fat pointer is sometimes useful, and even the standard library does it, so I wouldn't dismiss it as "absolutely unnecessary".

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Because you would have to create a variable that lives longer than the passed on, which isn't possible (without heap allocation). What you can achieve is returning an array as I suggested, e.g. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bfe368320279075887aac8bc2d091ec0

Comment: @SvenMarnach I wouldn't call the std library beginner friendly code in terms of "look at them what they did ;) ", do you have an examples ready?

Comment: @hellow One example is the `io::Read::read()` method impl for `&[u8]`. The type of the receiver is `&mut &[u8]`, and it advances the slice by the amount of bytes read – basically exactly what is done in this question, just for an immutable slice and with `u8` instead of `char`.

Comment: Okay I see, but that's because they type is `&[_]`. And I see, that [it advances is done by using `split_at`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/io/impls.rs.html#192-207). Hmm, that of course works, but is not really the same as OP wants. Would you like to answer @SvenMarnach

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error message is indeed unfortunate, and I don't think it provides a good explanation of what's going on here. The issue is a bit involved.

The error is local to the `advance_slice()` function, so that's all we need to look at. The type of the slice items is irrelevant, so let's take this function definition:

```
fn advance_slice_mut<T>(s: &mut &mut [T]) {
    let new = &mut s[1..];
    *s = new;
}
```

The first line creates a new slice object starting after the first item of the original slice.

Why is this even allowed? Don't we have *two* mutable references to the same data now? The original slice `*s` includes the new slice `new`, and both allow modifying data. The reason this is legal is that `*s` is *implicitly reborrowed* when creating the subslice, and `*s` cannot be used again for the lifetime of that borrow, so we still have only one active reference to the data in the subslice. The reborrow is scoped to the function `advance_slice_mut()`, and thus has a shorter lifetime than the original slice, which is the root cause of the error you get – you are effectively trying to assign a slice which only lives until the end of the function to a memory location that lives longer than the function call.

This kind of implicit reborrow happens everytime you call a function that takes an argument by mutable reference, including in the implicit call to `index_mut()` in `&mut s[1..]`. Mutable references can't be copied, since this would create two mutable references to the same memory, and the Rust language designers decided that an implicit reborrow is the more ergonomic solution than moving mutable references by default. The reborrow does not happen for *shared* references, though, since they can be freely copied. This means that `&s[1..]` will have the same lifetime as the original scope, since it is perfectly fine for two overlapping immutable slices to coexist. This explains why your function definition works fine for immutable slices.

So how do we fix this problem? I believe that what you intend to do is perfectly safe – after reassigning the new slice to the old one, the old one is gone, so we don't have two concurrent mutable references to the same memory. To create a slice with the same lifetime as the original slice in safe code, we need to move the original slice out of the reference we got. We can do this by replacing it with an empty slice:

```
pub fn advance_slice_mut<T>(s: &mut &mut [T]) {
    let slice = std::mem::replace(s, &mut []);
    *s = &mut slice[1..];
}
```

Alternatively, we can also resort to unsafe code:

```
use std::slice::from_raw_parts_mut;

pub fn advance_slice_mut<T>(s: &mut &mut [T]) {
    unsafe {
        assert!(!s.is_empty());
        *s = from_raw_parts_mut(s.as_mut_ptr().add(1), s.len() - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I filed an [issue for the confusing error message](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/62400).

Comment: Thank you very much for the elaborate answer. Side question : can we assume that `fn magic<'a,'b, T : ?Sized>(v :&'a mut &'b mut T) -> &'a mut &'b T` is safe ?

Comment: You *can* assume it's safe because the function is not marked as `unsafe`. It's up to whoever implemented the function to make sure all the required invariants hold true, even if they use `unsafe` blocks inside.

Comment: Sorry, my question is not very clear, what I was asking is: If I implement this function (using `unsafe`), would it follow the rust invariants ?

Comment: @PolyB I believe the function in my answer is safe from the caller's point of view.

Comment: @PolyB I just thought of a way of implementing this in safe code – please see the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer @SvenMarnach! I was struggling with a similar issue trying to advance a mutable slice, and this got me straightened out.